# How to add another data column to the Google Gantt Chart?

Tags: javascript, gantt-chart

[Example of tooltip of extra information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFPOd.png)
I wanted to add extra columns named as Budget and Progress, so that it will be shown on the tooltip when we hover at the bar.
Example screenshot as attached

I would just like to add another column in between any columns to get it populated via the array of objects.
Example:
data.addColumn('number', 'Budget Complete'); //this will load the integer values
data.addColumn('number', 'Progress'); //this will act like the percentage

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
  data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
  data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

  //console.log(data_objects);
  for (var i = 0; i < data_objects.length; i++) {

    arrd.push(data_objects[i].id,data_objects[i].text,data_objects[i].type,new Date(data_objects[i].start_date),new Date(data_objects[i].end_date),null,parseInt(data_objects[i].actual),checkParent(data_objects[i].parent));
    data.addRows([arrd]);
      //console.log(arrd);
      arrd = [];
  }
```

But it seems the API is not accepting more than these allowed columns.
Do you guys have any idea or suggestion on this?

Help much appreciated, thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately tooltip modifications are not supported for Gantt charts - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#supported-charts

Comment: Hi there, Link based answers can be made comments for better reach.